# Setting attribute using data from a for loop

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       var item = data[i];
       $('.client-content').append("<li>"+"<b>"+i +"</b>" + " : " +item[0] + " : " + item[1]+"<a href='#' class='link-right'>Edit</a>" + "<a href='#' class='link-right'>Delete</a>"+"</li>" + "<br/>");
```

`item[0]` is the record id that i want to have as my id attribute.I want my `<li>` to have the id `item[0]`.How do i do that?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       var item = data[i];
       $('.client-content').append("<li id='"+item [0]+"'>"+"<b>"+i +"</b>" + " : " +item[0] + " : " + item[1]+"<a href='#' class='link-right'>Edit</a>" + "<a href='#' class='link-right'>Delete</a>"+"</li>" + "<br/>");
```

Comment: I try getting the id now and its undefined.

Comment: so.... you dont have a value in item[0]